# form control triggers animation using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a `ul` that where I have 3 `li` that serves as containers and are animated. The two edge `li` will have some from controls (selectsand buttons). My issue is that using the control fires the animation which I don't want. Here is an exambple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FtrBP/). How can I prevent the select from firing the animation?  Thanks

Comment: I don't get the animation when interacting with the dropdown (Chrome).

Comment: Your code from fiddle should be included directly in your question too just in case jsfiddle goes down. Use the event.target property to ensure the element that triggered the event is the same element that you bound the event to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block the behavior if the event target is the select in question.

```
$('li#side-controls-container').on('click', function(){
    if ($(event.target).is('select')) { return; }
    ...
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JqJZ3/)**

**Suggestion:**

If you plan to have multiple controls, you may consider giving them all a specific class. Then you can check if the event target has that class instead of checking if it is a specific type of element.

```
$('li#side-controls-container').on('click', function(){
    if ($(event.target).is('.container-control')) { return; }
    ...
});
```